# attr_accessor does not work on associated objects that aren't saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I haven't been able to find an explanation as to why attr_accessor works here:

```
fb_profile = FbProfile.where(identifier: params[:identifier]).first_or_initialize
fb_profile.signed_request = "randomstring"
logger.info(fb_profile.signed_request) # outputs "randomstring"
```

but not here:

```
current_admin.fb_profile = FbProfile.where(identifier: params[:identifier]).first_or_initialize
current_admin.fb_profile.signed_request = "randomstring"
logger.info(current_admin.fb_profile.signed_request) # outputs undefined
```

I can work like in the first example, but then I have to create the association later, which seems dirtier than just creating it from the get go. Is this common behavior?

### Update1:

As some requested, here are the relevant parts of both models:

`class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise  :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
            :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
            :confirmable, :omniauthable
    include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
    has_one :fb_profile
end`

`class FbProfile < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :admin
    has_and_belongs_to_many :fb_pages
    attr_accessor :signed_request
end`

Comment: We need to see how is your relation between the class of ```current_admin``` and ```fb_profile``` and the exact error that is being shown.

Comment: You need to show the code in your FbProfile class and probably the Admin class or whatever class the current_admin is an object of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the relation between current_admin and fbprofile.

If you've a has_one relation I would write something like this :

```
current_admin.fb_profile ||= current_admin.build_fb_profile(identifier: params[:identifier])
```